# Object is not iterable Error while Using React-Context or In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

So I recently started using React and am learning the Context Api. The zest of my code is:

```js
export const UsersContext = createContext();
export function UsersProvider(props) {
    const fetchedItem = async function () {
        const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        const users = await data.json();
        setUsers(users);
    };
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(function () {
        fetchedItem();
    }, []);

    return (
        <UsersContext.Provider value={[users, setUsers]}>{props.children}</UsersContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And I try to import and iterate over the users array like so:

```js
import { UsersContext, UsersProvider } from './UsersContext';
export default function UsersPage() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useContext(UsersContext);
return (
        <UsersProvider>
{users.map(function (user) {
//I do something with user object});}
</UsersProvider>
```

The issue is this does not work and I am not sure what the terminologies are to search it on the web. I get `TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` which to me means that `users` is not an array? But it is as far as I am concerned.
Any suggestions for fixing/debugging this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using `useContext` outside of the provider, you should use `useContext` in a child component.

```js
import { UsersContext, UsersProvider } from './UsersContext';
export default function UsersPage() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useContext(UsersContext);
  return (
    <UsersProvider>
      {users.map(function (user) {
        <div key={user.id}>{user.id}</div>
      })}
    </UsersProvider>
  );
}
```

is the same as

```js
import { UsersContext, UsersProvider } from './UsersContext';
export default function UsersPage() {
  return (
    <UsersContext.Consumer>
      {([users, setUsers]) => (
        <UsersProvider>
          {users.map(function(user) {
            <div key={user.id}>{user.id}</div>;
          })}
        </UsersProvider>
      )}
    </UsersContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

as you can see the consumer is not a child of the provider, thus there is nothing provided to it. Consuming it in a child component works.

```js
import { UsersContext, UsersProvider } from './UsersContext';
export default function UsersPage() {
  return (
    <UsersProvider>
      <UsersPageChild />
    </UsersProvider>
  );
}

function UsersPageChild() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useContext(UsersContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map(function(user) {
        <div key={user.id}>{user.id}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow. I just wrapped the UsersPage with UsersProvider from the App component and It works. Thanks so much. I read that it had to be a child component but I was considering that everything inside UsersProvider is a child component as the stuff returned from it is = a component but I guess that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

This error may come in React when you are destructuring in wrong way.

Change from `const [resId] = useParams();` to `const {resId} = useParams();`

**Note: Check the brackets of resId. It could be possible you are using some other Hooks or Objects, but just check these brackets**

[image]