# How to fix: React-Context - TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have tried some solutions that came by, [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968735/object-is-not-iterable-error-while-using-react-context) particularily...

I tried changing value inside my TodosContext.js file.. which didn't work, too..
One more thing that I have tried is to call useContext() function from another component, that didn't work neither..

Here's my code.
App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import NewTodo from './components/NewTodo';
import { TodosProvider, TodosContext } from './components/contextapi/TodosContext';

function App() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [todos, setTodos] = useContext(TodosContext);

  const _handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }

  const _todoAdd = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      setTodos(
        [...todos, { content: input, id: Date.now(), completed: false }]
      )
      setInput('')
    }
  }

  const _todoRemove = (id) => {
    const newTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
    setTodos(newTodos)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h3>To-Do Manager | Context API</h3>
      </header>
      <TodosProvider>
        <NewTodo newTodo={_todoAdd} handleInput={_handleInput} newVal={input} />
        <TodoList todos={todos} />
      </TodosProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TodosContext.js:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const TodosContext = createContext()

export const TodosProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    return (
        <TodosContext.Provider value={[todos, setTodos]}>{children}</TodosContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

TodoList.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';
import RemoveTodoFromList from './RemoveTodoFromList';
import { TodosContext } from './contextapi/TodosContext'

function TodoList() {

    const [todos, setTodos] = useContext(TodosContext);

    return (
        <div>
            {todos.map(todo => (
                <div>
                    <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoList
```

I'm really struggling with this one, I spent whole day figuring out what went wrong.. Thanks!

Comment: Can u try `export const TodosContext = createContext([[],() => {}])`. This sets a default value on creation.

Comment: @Stutje Yeah man! It works! I really appreciate it, but is it necessary to write that syntax all the time or is it just in my case?

Comment: You should always give a default value in the `createContext` or at least specify it so you won't stumble into those annoying errors :) glad i could help

Answer (score 5):

We fixed it inside the comments.

`createContext` needs an object as parameter that defines your context.
In your case it should be `export const TodosContext = createContext([[],() => {}])`.
So the application knows the first element of the tuple is an array and so iterable.